# MICROSOFT AZURE INCREMENTAL BACKUP

Tags: sql-server, azure, backup, azure-sql-database, database-backups

Hi we are using Microsoft Azure to back up MS SQl DB as well some part of data  files. The backups works smooth for an year now. We set up the frequency for these incremental backups as 3 times a day. on normal back up Azure takes a 50 to 80 MB backup and on after each two days it taking 800 MB to 1000 MB as back up also in the first session of the day. This 800 to 1000 MB cause my network overload sometime. So I want to know how can I find why this is happening after each two days and how can I stop this or else how can I shift this abnormal back up ( as per my assumption)  to some other timings at night.

Comment: Are you backing up an on-premises SQL Server, or are you backing up an Azure SQL Database?

Comment: Are you using long-term backup retention using  Azure Recovery Services vault?

Comment: Can you provide more details on the backup? Is it an export as a bacpac?

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to Azure Backup Agent, the Azure backup agent provides network throttling. Throttling controls how network bandwidth is used during data transfer. This control can be helpful if you need to back up data during work hours but do not want the backup process to interfere with another Internet traffic. Throttling applies to back up and restore activities.
For more information refer the section “[Enable network throttling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-configure-vault)”